# Exercise about Venn diagrams and Cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

> In a survey of 480 students at a  university. The following information  was collected. Of those surveyed, 200 students liked the subjects that involved mathematics, 260 students liked the subjects that involved programming,170 students disliked subjects involving physics, and 250 of them liked subjects involving two topics combined. Could you find out, how many students liked the subjects that involved all three topics combined?

First, i try to know the cardinality of the following sets:

- Students that liked math and physics
- Students that liked math and programming
- Students that liked physics and programming
  But i not sure how i can find these, because im a litle confused with all the variables.

Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I have tried to compute the cardinalities of the intersections between each of the sets mentioned above, for this I have tried to use the cardinalities of the complements as well as the formulas of inclusion exclusion, but I am not sure if this is correct because the equations that I have obtained so far always have more than one variable and I do not see how I could build a system where I can relate them all to each other.

Comment: You should put this info in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $480-170=310$ students who like physics. Now denote the quantity of those who like maths and physics but not programming by $a$, those who like physics and programming but not maths by $b$, those who like programming and maths but not physics by $c$, those who like all three by $x$. Then we have the following equations:

$$\begin{cases} a+b+x=310\\ b+c+x=260\\ c+a+x=200 \end{cases}$$

Add these equations and get:

$$2(a+b+c)+3x=770.$$

Since $a+b+c=250$, we have $$x=90.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aig!  I thought I had to necessarily know the values of a,b and c, but now I see that it was not necessary

Comment: @Nick_W This solution is wrong though. I assumed that every student who likes a topic, likes at least two topics. Which is not true. But this also shows that there is not enough data in your problem. If I decrease $310$ to $307$ in my system, making $3$ students who only like physics, we still would be able to find $x$ from it. It would be $89$. So the problem obviously lacks data.